# How to make a waterfall toolbar in Android?

Tags: android

I was exploring this app named [ThemeDIY](https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=net.darkion.theme.maker&rdid=net.darkion.theme.maker) when I saw this beautiful waterfall toolbar. If you look well, you'll see that shadow doesn't get animated (like [Google's](https://material-components-web.appspot.com/toolbar/index.html)), it appears as you pull. Just awesome.
Does anyone knows how to do that?

https://youtu.be/b3m1kkqUrx8

Comment: You would need to add a scroll listener to the scrollable view and set the Toolbar [elevation](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/view/View.html#setElevation(float)) from the listener.

Comment: Yes, that's what I've done by now. I'll share my waterfall toolbar library soon.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I made a library for it based on a scrollview's or recyclerview's scroll.
https://github.com/HugoCastelani/waterfall-toolbar